# Is it correct to use she in my sentence?

Tags: pronouns, personal-pronouns

> Another negative experience with that **doctor** was when **she** did not provide enough explanation about that investigation.

Should I use "she" or another pronoun?

Comment: Costas, please edit your question to tell us why you think "she" might be the wrong pronoun.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the doctor's gender, if you do not know the gender of the doctor, you can simply say the following:

> Another negative experience with that doctor was when **he or she** did not provide enough explanation about that investigation.

Or an increasingly popular choice is using the *singular* **they** - gender neutral pronoun:

> Another negative experience with that doctor was when **they** did not provide enough explanation about that investigation.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the doctor is in fact female, "she" is a perfectly proper pronoun, and no other seems likely to be better, unless you know that the doctor prefers another pronoun, as some people now do. If you do not know the doctor's gender, you could use "he or she", "s/he", or "they".